# How to log user into google?

Tags: google-oauth

I am making a single sign on solution for multiple products and need to be able to log the user into their google account so that they can use other google services like drive and email etc. I am getting access tokens and storing them using the Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc and sample code but I am unsure how to use this token to log the user in. I don't need api access just need to ensure that after the user has gone through the flow the next time they visit my site they are logged into their google account. This is a .net mvc project.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, flowData).AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (result == null || result.Credential == null)
            return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);

        return new RedirectResult(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
    }

            initiater = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {             
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "30725746816-ev4dn6bt84cmj8ksemsrh894lcngh45q.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "-Sm8vvVjlIsR8M4AxMR8-MZw",
            },
            Scopes = new[] { "openid profile email" },
            DataStore = new GoogleIDataStore(_session, user),
        };

        currentUser = user;

        flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(initiater);
```

Comment: Please add the code attempts that you've made, so that people answering the question know where you're running into trouble.

Comment: You can only do that using Google Apps for Work with SSO/SAML.

Comment: Any example  code on how to integrate Google Apps for Work with SSO/SAML.